# Sharepoint's Client Object Model with Silverlight, is it possible to load web.Language with executeQuery?

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-clientobject

Is this:

```
Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(web, w => w.Language);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

or something similar in order to load `web.Language` with `context.ExecuteQuery()` possible in a silverlight client? The above code was taken from
http://www.dev4side.com/community/blog/2011/1/5/incorrect-dates-taken-from-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model.aspx

When I do so, instantiating the `web`'s `Language` property always yields
    `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException`

Btw, this code is in an extra thread (not the UI thread). I know that there is `context.loadQueryAsync()` but I already have an extra thread and would like to keep things together.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've tried this code works ok. Do you maybe access some other properties of the Web object that are not loaded? You'd have to include them also in your load method.